# No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #2) in @GET call

Tags: android, json, api, android-studio, retrofit2

I'm trying to get some data from a movie api. I try to make a call with retrofit like usual but it occured an error with the second parameter. It's probably because the String parameter videos (in the link that generates the Json file) it's not a "variable" parameter, so maybe it did not recognize the call.

Service:

```
public interface Service {

@GET("/3/movies/{id}")
Call<TrailerResponse> getVideos (
        @Path("id") int id,
        String videos,
        @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
        @Query("language") String language
);
}
```

Load (the variables in getVideos I don't think are important to specify)

```
    public static List<Videos> load() {
    Service apiService = Client.getClient().create(Service.class);
    Call<TrailerResponse> call;
    call = apiService.getVideos(ID, VIDEOS, API_KEY, LANGUAGE);
    if(call == null){
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to remove the `videos` parameter, and just add it to the path of the url.

Also, if you look at [the documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-videos), the path should be `movie` instead of `movies`, and the ID parameter should be `movie_id` instead of `id`

```
public interface Service {

@GET("/3/movie/{id}/videos")
Call<TrailerResponse> getVideos (
        @Path("movie_id") int id,
        @Query("api_key") String apiKey,
        @Query("language") String language
);
}
```